# Java infinite loop error while calling stored procedure

Tags: java

I am writing a Java web application, in which I am calling a stored procedure.

If the stored procedure went into an infinite loop, how could I handle the infinite loop on the Java side?

Comment: The only way you could possibly handle it is to set a timeout.

Comment: As @litelite said, you can add timeout. But also consider fixing the stored procedure infinite loop :)

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure that is causing the infinite loop?!

Comment: Thanks for the response........ I am using PostgreSql Database..i wrote a stored procedure to retrieve the data from 3 tables to show in report....Recently i faced a problem in db cause we are using DB link to connect to other database which is taking more than 5 min to retrieve the data.some times the query runs for infinite time .

Answer (score 0):

Use `Try Catch` statement to catch the exception causing the infinite loop, if you are using `while` you should use try like this example:

```
While(true){
     try{
      // your code for calling the stored procedure
        }
     catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
       }
    }
```

The exception depends on the database you are using, for example `SqlException` if you are using SQL server.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, the infinite loop is inside the stored procedure. OP does not want to call a procedure in an infinite loop, he wants to know how to react to one.

Answer (score 0):

The only viable way to deal with an infinite loop inside a stored procedure, is to set a timeout; That is due to the fact that computers cannot [reliably detect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) infinite loops, so the best you can do is give-up after a resonnable amount of time. The way to set that timeout and how that timeout is reported changes from tool to tool. Please refer to the documentation of the one you are using if you want to know how to set one.

OR as [Vishal Kamat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6276864/vishal-kamat) said, you should consider fixing the infinite loop at the source if it is possible.